# Jquery move divs from right to left with right positions

Tags: jquery

I want to make divs move from one side to another. Like when I  click on menu, div comes from right, then I click next menu, this div goes left and new div comes. But I have problems with positions. Divs come from bottom of page, then appear in center. I don know how to fix it.

Here is my code:

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my.css">
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li id= "home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li id= "about"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li id= "products"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li id= "services"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li id= "contact"><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id = "newdiv"   style="height:400px; width:700px; background-color:red;    display:none;   margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; "></div>
  <div id = "newdiv1"  style="height:400px; width:700px; background-color:blue;   display:none;   margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; "></div>
  <div id = "newdiv2"  style="height:400px; width:700px; background-color:yellow; display:none;   margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; "></div>
  <div id = "newdiv3"  style="height:400px; width:700px; background-color:green;  display:none;   margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; "></div>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is my script.js.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#home").click(function() {
         $(".myclass").toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 2000).removeClass();
         $("#newdiv").addClass('myclass').toggle("slide", { direction: "right" }, 2000);
    });

    $("#about").click(function() {
        $(".myclass").toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 2000).removeClass();
        $("#newdiv1").addClass('myclass').toggle("slide", { direction: "right" }, 2000);
    });

    $("#products").click(function() {
         $(".myclass").toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 2000).removeClass();
         $("#newdiv2").addClass('myclass').toggle("slide", { direction: "right" }, 2000);
    });

    $("#services").click(function() {
          $(".myclass").toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 2000).removeClass();
          $("#newdiv3").addClass('myclass').toggle("slide", { direction: "right" }, 2000);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `position:absolute` on the divs.

Like:

```
<div id = "newdiv" style=" position:absolute; height:400px; width:700px; background-color:red;    display:none;  position:absolute;  margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; "></div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V9G6Q/)

Comment: Yeah, thanks for answer. But when I use `position:absolute` it works all differently. It does not come from right and go left, it just appears, and not in center, but in left side.

Comment: it also does not help :(